# When should I use each option of Android Project View at Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am used to Eclipse and now I am switching to Android Studio. There are three options in Android Project View: project, packages and android.
In which occasion should I use each of this view options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use whichever presents the project structure in a way that makes sense to you. They are simply different ways of viewing (mostly) the same information.

**Project** shows all the files within the project directory- this includes IntelliJ configuration files, exectuables, and other such files that you probably don't need to access often (if at all).

**Pacakage** shows all of your resources and java code grouped by their package (or in the case of resources, by their folder structure).

**Android** is a special view developed by Google for viewing Android projects. It does some useful grouping for you. For example, if you have a layout called `activity_main.xml` that you provide different copies of for different screen sizes, it will group all those copies under a single `activity_main.xml` entry so that you don't have to jump between folders to find the different versions.

Answer (score 0):

All views just give you the same information more or less. I always use `Android` view. It feels better and more elegant than the rest.

It all comes down to which view you prefer and which view makes you have better access to what you want at the time.